# PHP replace all characters with asterisk

Tags: php

So lets say I have a password in the form of a string:

```
$password = "thisisaplaintextpassword"
```

How can I turn it into the following?

```
$password = "************************"
```

I would like to send users their account details via email, and don't want to send the entire thing.

Comment: `and don't want to send the entire thing.`.. Then why you are trying to send the password if it is not needed?

Comment: @u_mulder the password length varies

Comment: If no one can see it - 1. Why send it? 2. Who cares what length is it?

Comment: @Jenz so they can see the length of the password

Comment: why does all this matter? if you don't know how to do this then just don't answer, go bother another asker

Comment: Because you are asking not to show the password, i guess you storing the password in plain text. Never store plain text passwords! there are some best practices to save passwords as a salted hashed value. Otherwise if you database is stolen your problems are a little bigger.

Comment: @BerndOtt Well its an sqlite database and i use prepared statements. Yes the passwords are plain text. But the only way to compromise it would be if they got my FTP credentials right?

Comment: @ThatGuy343 or you are storing it into webroot or your server-software has a bug or a php programms allows path traversal or or or or. there are so many possibilities - simply don't do it. Btw. it is not good that you know their passwords. most people are lazy and using the same pw for everything.

Comment: @BerndOtt i'm begging to see that i was going about this all wrong, I'm going to hash them instead

Comment: It is bad practice storing the password in your database in plain text. Just a friendly reminder.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
$password = str_repeat("*", strlen($password));
```

Answer (score 10):

You should not really be showing the length to the user, as that is leaking information that should be secure.

The socratic method being used here in the comments below your question in asking "why you want to do that?" is more advice "don't do that", but socratic method is supposed to encourage you to think about why the question is being asked. The conclusion you're supposed to draw is "you should not be asking that specific question, because the basis for the question is flawed". Just use a static string. This is better advice than actually telling you how to do something that is the wrong thing to do in the given situation.

Secondly: to be showing the user a sequence of asterisks that reflect the length of their password is kind of suggesting you're storing their password in either clear text or only encrypting it so that you can revert it to its original form to determine the length. This is betraying further lack of security on your part. Unless there is a very good reason not to, only a hash of a password should ever be stored. And hashes are a uniform length, so that makes your question redundant.

So you - quite simply - should not be doing this. *That* is the answer to the bottom line of the question you're asking.

However for the sake of completeness, I'll repeat the answer you have already in other responses:

```
function stringToAsterisks($string){
    return str_repeat("*", strlen($string)); 
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Comment: I see, thank you for this insight. This is my first time setting up an account system.

Comment: No probs: we all start somewhere, and some of this stuff is not immediately obvious first time round. Can I suggest you don't invent the whole thing yourself, but instead read up on how best to approach this sort of thing, especially when it comes to securing people's data.

Comment: For debugging it is very useful to know the length of a password, after all it can be seen whether the password is missing or is too short. On the other hand it is simply irrelevant whether a brute-force attack takes a few thousand or a few mllion years.

Answer (score 2):

```
function hidePassword($p) {
    $fit = strlen($p);
    return sprintf("%'*-${fit}s",false);
}

echo hidePassword($p);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$password = "thisisaplaintextpassword"
echo str_repeat("*",strlen($password));
```

Sample Input

```
testingpass
```

Sample Output

```
***********
```

Sample Input

```
hello
```

Sample Output

```
*****
```